# How to append two columns with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to clean outliers in dataset with the loop:

```
df_cleaned = pd.DataFrame()

for grade in df.Grade.unique():
    df_per_grade = df[df['Grade']==grade]
    for column in df_per_grade.columns[5:-2]:
        df_clean = pd.DataFrame(df_per_grade['Grade', 'Shift'])
        df_clean[column] = df_per_grade[column][df_per_grade[column].between(df_per_grade[column].quantile(0.05), 
                                df_per_grade[column].quantile(0.95))]
        df_cleaned = df_cleaned.append(df_clean)
```

the problem is that it is returning me data set that look like this:

```
Index | Grade | Shift | Column 1 | Column 2 |
  0       P1      1         5         NaN
  1       P1      1         3         NaN
  2       P2      1         2         NaN
  3       P2      1         1         NaN
  4       P2      1         2         NaN
  0       P1      1        NaN         7
  1       P1      1        NaN         9
  2       P2      1        NaN         9
  3       P2      1        NaN         7
  4       P2      1        NaN         5
```

And I would like want it too look like this:

```
Index | Grade | Shift | Column 1 | Column 2 |
   0       P1      1         5         7
   1       P1      1         3         9
   2       P2      1         2         9
   3       P2      1         1         7
   4       P2      1         2         5
```

Comment: use pd.concat, and not pd.append, with axis=1, it will solve your problem

Comment: Hi, it is giving me an error KeyError: ('Grade', 'Shift')

Comment: what is the precise line you wrote?

Comment: I have figured it out why is giving me a previous error, but now is telling me that: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'

Comment: I have written df_cleaned = pd.concat([df_cleaned, df_clean], axis=0) and it is giving me a same issue

Comment: as i said in the first comment, please write axis=1

Answer (score 1):

Do not use append on the last code line. Use merge instead :

```py
df_cleaned = df_cleaned.merge(df_clean)
```

Comment: KeyError: ('Grade', 'Shift')

Comment: use -> `df_cleaned.merge(df_clean, on = 'Index')`

Comment: Hi, I have figured out what was wrong previously, but now when I try merge it is giving me: MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False